# How to change regular js file to min.js automatically?

Tags: javascript, automation, gulp, min, production

Hi how can i use gulp so that when I upload my index.html to the server, the javascript file gets the minified by itself. so for development purpose I can have the regular javascript file and when its uploaded it changes to the min.js version

Comment: by uploaded you mean your app is deployed to server or what? can you please be more clear/specific

Answer (score 1):

Another term for minify is uglify:

You can read more about it here for gulp

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify

## Usage

```
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
 
gulp.task('compress', function() {
  return gulp.src('lib/*.js')
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```